# Finding where a(n expensive) function == 1

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, sampling

I have a finite range of scalars, e.g. X∈ [0,10]. I also have a complicated and expensive (to compute) function, *f*, that given x∈ X, I get a value of 0 or 1 (I can also get a Real number that determines if the output is 0 or 1 based on some threshold, if it helps. E.g. *f*(x)=1 if some value a>5 inside the function, and 0 - otherwise).

I would like to find the regions where the function *f* evaluated to 1. I do not have access to ∇*f*(x), and sampling x's uniformly would be too expensive, and "deterministically sampling" (ie equal-distance grid) from the range is too expensive, too. [Root finding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms) (as far as I can tell), would also be too expensive, not to mention how to find **all** of the "roots".

I'm currently thinking about two ideas. The first is Bayesian global optimization with Gaussian processes, [for example](https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization), so that I can sample more intelligently in places with low uncertainty of the values of the function *f*. This is why maybe the Real value would be better than 0/1 because it may model a smoother function better.

The second idea is doing some kind of [cross-entropy optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-entropy_method), again to sample better from *f*.

I was wondering if there are better ideas to find those sections in which *f*(x) rises to 1 and decreases to 0? I understand that I will not get exact solutions and it is fine, but I'd like it to be as close as can be with some smart algorithm.

Python implementation is especially welcomed but would accept others and I'll convert it.

Comment: "I also have a complicated and expensive (to compute) function" Depending on *what kind of function it is*, this could vary from trivial to effectively impossible. But as a hint: if you could determine, ahead of time, the *inverse* function (i.e., `g` such that `g(f(x)) == x` for all `x`), do you see how that would help solve the problem? Yes, if `f` has multiple roots then you'd also need some kind of domain/range analysis. But the point is, viewed that way, this is a *symbolic computation* problem. Hopefully that helps you research the question more.

Comment: Actually hold on. To be clear: the domain is *real numbers* in some finite interval, and the range is exactly the set `{0, 1}`? But that value specifically comes from thresholding an ordinary real-to-real function, so actually what you want is to find the points where that function intersects the threshold. Yes, in the latter case that's root-finding; subtract the threshold (as a constant function) from the original function, and find the zeros of that. Both numeric and symbolic approaches exist.

Comment: Are you able to share with us `f(x)`?  That may shed some light on potential optimizations

Comment: Ok, I wasn't clear - I do not have access to `f`'s internals (other than the real value it can output or the {0,1}), **consider it to be a black box function** that is very complicated that only depends on x but in highly non-linear ways. Obtaining the inverse function is impossible. How do I get `f(x1)f(x2)<0` to do root finding? On what domains? Also, no gradients for `f` exist.

Comment: @GuyS Unless you can create some bounds on the behavior of the real-valued function, there is no way to solve this.  If you can bound, say, the first and second derivatives of the real-valued function, then it is possible to try to solve this.

Comment: @btilly I know I can't find exact solutions, but I'm looking for approximate solutions. I got pretty far with Bayesian optimization, but after reading your comment, I see that I made an implicit assumption that the true function `f` is continuous and smooth, which I shouldn't. I need to play with some examples to see if there are any kernels that could still try to deal with non smooth functions.

Comment: @GuyS Any approximate solution will make assumptions about what approximations work.  If those approximations are valid, it will be useful, else not.  You really can't get something for nothing.